# Why did Cardinal Cupich prohibit Traditional Latin Mass on First Sundays?

Tags: catholicism, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, traditionis-custodes

Cardinal Cupich ordered no TLM Masses on several days of the year:

> The new policy also prohibits the celebration of Traditional Latin Masses on the first Sunday of every month, Christmas, the Triduum, Easter Sunday, and Pentecost Sunday.

https://www.ncregister.com/cna/cardinal-cupich-issues-new-restrictions-on-traditional-latin-masses

Other than spreading confusion and chaos, what reason could he have for preventing TLM to be celebrated on First Sundays?  I've heard of First Fridays, I've heard of First Saturdays, but First Sundays are new to me.

Answer (score 3):

**Why did [Cardinal Cupich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blase_J._Cupich) prohibit Traditional Latin Mass on First Sundays?**

He simply chose the First Sunday of each month as well as the major feasts of Christmas, the Triduum, Easter Sunday, and Pentecost Sunday, **as a way to test the obedience of TLM faithful**.

There is nothing special about First Sundays according to Catholic tradition or piety. He simply chose these days in which to restrict the Mass of Pope St. Pius V.

Nowhere in [***Traditionis Custodes***](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html) does it require that a local bishop restrict the TLM from being celebrated on certain days of the year. Thus Cardinal Cupich is simply making a personal statement on the issue at hand.

> Chicago's new rules mirror those spelled out in an explanatory document regarding Pope Francis' edict published Dec. 18 by the Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the Sacraments.
>
> **The new policy also prohibits the celebration of Traditional Latin Masses on the first Sunday of every month, Christmas, the Triduum, Easter Sunday, and Pentecost Sunday.**
>
> “My intention in sharing this policy is to encourage you to reflect on the duty we each must assist our people in this moment of Eucharistic revival by rediscovering the value of the liturgical reform in the rites given to us by the Second Vatican Council,” Cardinal Cupich wrote in an accompanying letter to priests, Vatican News reported.
>
> The Vatican's explanatory document states that the intent of Traditionis custodes is “to re-establish in the whole Church of the Roman Rite a single and identical prayer expressing its unity, according to the liturgical books promulgated by the Popes Saint Paul VI and Saint John Paul II, in conformity with the decrees of the Second Vatican Council and in line with the tradition of the Church.”
>
> [Cardinal Cupich Issues New Restrictions on Traditional Latin Masses](https://www.ncregister.com/cna/cardinal-cupich-issues-new-restrictions-on-traditional-latin-masses)

Some of Cardinal Cupich assumptions as well as those outlined in **Traditionis custodes** do not add up in my humble way of seeing things. Both agree to limit the Ancient Liturgy of Pope St. Pius V in order **”to re-establish in the whole Church of the Roman Rite a single and identical prayer expressing its unity.”**

Historically, this makes no sense. The Roman Rite, even under Pope St. Pius V had several Roman Rites and Usages within the Latin Rite. There was unity in diversity and the Church was united. Cardinal Cupich is creating division and is willfully doing it.

Take away the most sacred feasts away from traditionalists and there is going to be a reaction very soon. Things are going to come to a breaking point at some time or other.

At present there are a total number of 23 Eastern Rite Catholic Traditions in use at the present moment. On January 19, 2015 Pope Francis established the [Eritrean Catholic Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eritrean_Catholic_Church).

On July 7, 2007 Pope Benedict XVI issued his Apostolic Letter [Summorum Pontificum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summorum_Pontificum) in which he permitted the Mass of Pope St Pius V to be used in the Roman Catholic Rite. The Sovereign Pontiff also declared that there would be two forms of celebrating the Mass in the Roman Rite: The Ordinary Form of the Mass of Pope Blessed Paul VI (April 3,1969) and the Extraordinary Form of the Mass of Pope St Pius V (July 14 1570). Pope Benedict XVI went on to declare that the Mass of Pope Pius V had never been abrogated and could thus be lawfully used in the Church.

The Ordinary Form of the Mass has one form in usage, with at least two usages permitted within the Ordinary Form of Pope Paul VI. The Tridentine Rite or the Extraordinary Form is a little more complex to explain. This Rite had many "Rites" and "Usages" that were permitted up to the time of the Second Vatican Council. The difference between a rite and/or usage is not always clear in terms of terminology.

In the following list of Rites and Uses I am employing are of the most common ones which can be found in liturgical books of the day such as the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/). Some rites or usages of the Roman Rite were Diocese restricted, while others were restricted to particular religious Orders and as such were not bound to geographical regions.  This is not a complete list of former rites and/or usages.

**The Ordinary Form**

- Mass of Pope Paul VI.............In use
- [Anglican Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_ordinariate)...........................In use
- [Zaire Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaire_Use)..................................In use
- Carthusian Use.......................In use

**The Extraordinary Form**

- Mass of Pope Pius V...........................In use
- Ambrosian Rite (Milan, Italy)..........Used on occasion
- Mozarabic Rite (Spain)......................Used on occasion
- [Lyonese Rite](http://theradtrad.blogspot.ca/2014/10/is-braga-french-rite.html) (Lyon, France).............Used on occasion
- Benevento Rite.....................................Defunct
- [Greek Rite](http://www.newliturgicalmovement.org/2011/07/glagolitic-missal-missale-romanum.html).............................................No info.
- [Slavonic Rite](http://www.carpatho-rusyn.org/spirit/chap5.htm).........................................No info.
- [Rite of Braga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rite_of_Braga).........................................Permitted to be used
- Usages of Paris ([Rite of Versailles](http://theradtrad.blogspot.ca/2014/10/is-braga-french-rite.html))..Suppressed
- [Rouen Usage](http://theradtrad.blogspot.ca/search/label/Missale%20Rotomagensis).........................................No info.
- Esztergom Use......................................Defunct
- Nidaros Use (Norway)........................Defunct
- Cologne Use..........................................No info.
- Marseille Use.........................................No info
- Slevig Use (Denmark).........................Defunct
- Rosslyn Use...........................................No info.
- [Sarum Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarum_Rite)..............................................Used on occasion
- York Use.................................................No info.
- Hereford Use.........................................No info
- Lincoln Use............................................No info.
- Durham Use...........................................Defunct
- Bangor Use..............................................No info.
- Carmelite Rite........................................No info.
- [Cistercian Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariawald_Abbey)........................................In use
- Dominican Rite......................................In use
- Norbertine Rite......................................No info.
- Franciscan Rite.......................................No info (Same as the Tridentine mass)
- Friars Minor Capuchin Rite.................No info.
- Servite Rite...............................................No info.
- [Benedictine Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontgombault_Abbey)......................................In use
- [Carthusian Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthusians).......................................Permitted to be used

Traditionalists should not be forced to abandon their liturgies on the most sacred of Feast days and then again on some other random Sundays. Where is the supernatural charity in all that. All in the name of having just one ***Rite*** within the **Roman Rite**. I guess there is no longer unity with diversity.

> It is all humbug I say! - Ebenezer Scrooge

The following may be of interest to some:

- [Cardinal Cupich faces clash of ideas and reality over Traditionis custodes](https://www.pillarcatholic.com/p/cardinal-cupich-faces-clash-of-ideas)
- [Cardinal Cupich limits traditional liturgy in Chicago archdiocese](https://www.catholicculture.org/news/headlines/index.cfm?storyid=53348) *The Vatican News web site gave prominent coverage to the Chicago policy, clearly indicating the Vatican’s approval.*

Comment: "Cardinal Cupich is creating division and is willfully doing it."- How can you accuse an anointed Successor of Apostle of creating division, when he simply uphold the guidelines in Traditionis Custodes?

Comment: @jongricafort Traditionalists should not be forced to abandon their liturgies on the most sacred of Feast days and then again on some other random Sundays. Where is the supernatural charity in all that. Post your own answer if you think otherwise.

Comment: Have you seen how Abraham was forced to sacrifice his only beloved son? When God wanted to test the obedience of the faithful, God will ask us, our "Isaac" or the most precious one, the one thing that really matter to us. Is the TLM the Isaac of the Trads that Pope Francis and the Vatican II was inspired to know the hearts of the Trads?

Comment: @jongricafort nothing in Traditionis Custodes requires that a local bishop restrict the TLM from being celebrated on certain days of the year.

Comment: @jaredad7 The Bishop has the Canonical Power or jurisdiction on his diocese, and he can suspend the faculties of all priest if he wanted too.

Comment: Yes, he *can*, but you are saying that he is being obedient to Rome *in doing so*. These are very different claims.

Comment: @jaredad7 Read this canonical power. Art. 2. It belongs to the diocesan bishop, as moderator, promoter, and guardian of the whole liturgical life of the particular Church entrusted to him, [5] to regulate the liturgical celebrations of his diocese. [6] Therefore, it is his exclusive competence to authorize the use of the 1962 Roman Missal in his diocese, according to the guidelines of the Apostolic See.https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html

Comment: @jongricafort no one is disputing that the motu proprio gives Cupich the canonical right to do what he is doing. It also does not compel him to do what he is doing, so stating that he is doing what he is doing in obedience to Rome is not a true statement. Card. Cupich is not being forced to do this. Other bishops have chosen to allow the TLM to continue mostly unaffected in their diocese, except where their hands *are actually bound* by the motu proprio. Cupich is clearly doing this because he has a problem with the Latin Mass, a fact evident from his past actions regarding the TLM in Chicago.

Comment: @jaredad7 And that problem is the main reason why TC was inspired by the Holy Spirit. Remember the College of Bishops reported the real situation or the evil fruits of Summorum P. and Pope Francis united with the College of Bishops is guided by the Holy Spirit the Spirit of Truth, they cannot err. -John16:12-14

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see which Bishops in which colleges responded to his survey, what they said, and what evidence they used to back their claims. Did they focus only on the worst groups and ignore those who lived faithfully and obediently? And you are mistaken, the Pope and the Bishops can err in matters of legality. They can err in what prescriptions they impose on the faithful. TC is not a matter of faith nor morals.

Answer (score 2):

#### **Too long for a comment :**

> <sup>Dcn. Andy:</sup> The Latin Church can only properly have one rite

*If this is indeed the case* (and I'm not arguing that it isn't, merely drawing attention to this statement's potential importance), then it would constitute *yet another difference* between Orthodoxy and Roman Catholicism, inasmuch as the [Eastern and Oriental churches usually have more than one official rite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(liturgy)#Antiochene_Rites); speaking for the former, there are three main (types of) liturgies, continuously in use since the first millennium:

- [of John Chrysostom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_Saint_John_Chrysostom),
- [of Basil the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_Saint_Basil),
- [of Gregory the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_the_Presanctified_Gifts).

The **Egyptian** church commonly employs [three Coptic liturgies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_Rite#Divine_Liturgy), namely:

- [of Cyril of Alexandria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_Saint_Cyril), a variant of that of Mark the Evangelist,
- [of Basil the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_Saint_Basil#Coptic_Liturgy) (distinct from the above),
- [of Gregory Nazianzen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_of_Saint_Gregory).

The **Assyrian** church also makes frequent use of [three sacred *qurbana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Qurbana#Qudasha_of_Saints_Addai_and_Mari) in its [three Nestorian liturgies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Syriac_Rite#The_Eucharistic_service), namely:

- [of the Holy Apostles Addai and Mari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_Addai_and_Mari),
- [of Nestorius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallowing_of_Nestorius) himself,
- [of Theodore the Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallowing_of_Theodore_of_Mopsuestia).

The **Syrian** church employs [dozens of Syriac anaphoras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(liturgy)#Syro-Antiochene_Rite), and over seventy belong to the **Maronite** church; a mixed list of liturgies belonging to *both of these rites*, about forty in number, being found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Syriac_Rite#:%7E:text=Xystus).

---

**To make it *crystal* clear, (most of) these liturgies are *universally* employed within *each* of their respective denominations, depending on liturgical season; they are *not local rites*.**

Comment: If it's true that the Latin Church can only have one rite, then we also need to throw out all of the traditional rites of various Latin religious orders, which seems incredibly unjust and pointless.

Comment: @jaredad7: Not necessarily, since, technically speaking, they are not literally Roman; i.e., they do not belong to, nor are celebrated within the actual city of Rome; hence the presence of the emboldened sentence at the very end of my answer.

Comment: Then, if other Latin Rites should not be infringed due to their association with an order, rather than the secular Church, the celebration of the TLM must be permitted for the ICKSP and the FSSP and the SSPX, since this is their sacred rite.

Comment: At least [one such order exists within Cupich's domain](https://www.latinmassdir.org/venue/shrine-of-christ-the-king-icksp-chicago/), and he either has no right to restrict their celebration of the TLM, *or* he has every right to restrict the celebration of the Domincan Rite, the Benedictine Rite, the Carmelite Rite, etc, for any of those communities in his diocese. Each of these orders belongs to the Latin tradition of the Catholic Church.

Answer (score -1):

*Why did Cardinal Cupich prohibit Traditional Latin Mass on First Sundays?*

The simple answer is **"Obedience to the Pope".**

Pope Francis issued a motu proprio in Traditionis Custodes, and this must be uphold or follow by all Bishops in the Catholic Church.

A Bishop ignoring this important guidelines, is not in harmony with the inspired wisdom of the Holy Spirit to Pope Francis, who is acting like Jesus Christ in following the Will of the Father, to foster unity in celebrating the Holy Eucharist.

Cardinal Cupich wisdom is great, and must be emulated by all bishops in the world. Why? If a Bishop wanted to know the number of schismatic priests in his diocese, then, *Traditionis Custodes* is a powerful instrument to expose or reveal the hearts of the priest under his watch. Also, the Bishop will also know the number of their followers.

We have to remember the prophecy of Archbishop Fulton Sheen, on the emergence of the counterfeit church that resembles the old Catholic Church but ***"emptied of divine content"***. How will this unfold? Very simple.

1. A Priest celebrating the TLM without authorization from Rome and without Bishop permission is obviously illicit.
2. Article #5, also used the term *"priestly faculties is suspended"*. If the priestly faculty to celebrate the TLM is suspended, what will happen to the *"bread & wine"*, will the Holy Spirit descend on the sacrifice tainted with disobedience? In the case  of King Saul in 1Samuel15:22, a sacrifice offered in disobedience, is rejected by God, it means, the TLM offered in disobedience is *"devoid of divine content"*, meaning the *"bread & wine"* was not sanctified. Or in the words of Cdl.Cupich it is an *"Invalid consecration".*

The most important question is, since Traditionis Custodes guidelines were clearly expounded and explained in answer to the Dubia. Since the guidelines is now more clearly explained. The simple but important question is,...

Will the known schismatic priest who intentionally celebrate the TLM without seeking permission to his Bishop and worst, do not have authorization from Rome...

> **Will the Holy Spirit descend on the "bread & wine" knowing the priestly faculties of the schismatic priest is suspended by the decree in Traditionis Custodes?**

**The biblical answer is NO** - 1 Samuel 15:22. And this will make the TLM celebrated by schismatic priest not only illicit, but also *"invalid"* because the consecration was not confected. So, the TLM is like the offering of King Saul, beautiful on the outside but devoid of divine content, because the offering was not sanctified by the Holy Spirit.[image]

Comment: I agree that Cardinal Cupich did what he did to test the obedience of the traditionalists. However, Archbishop Fulton Sheen has not been beatified as of yet. On December 3, 2019, the Diocese of Peoria announced that the Holy See had decided on December 2 that Sheen's beatification would be "postponed". As of December 2021, the Attorney General has not released any report criticizing Sheen, and the Vatican has not announced when or if the beatification will move ahead. According the title of ***Blessed*** as you have, can impede a ***Servant of God’s*** beatification process.

Comment: “[Satan] will set up a counterchurch which will be the ape of the [Catholic] Church. . . . It will have all the notes and characteristics of the Church, but in reverse and emptied of its divine content.” - spoken words of Archbishop Fulton Sheen in 1948. Words spoken about the future: The New Mass was established in 1967!

Comment: @KenGraham Its the wisdom behind seeing the Vatican II as a New Church, because of Archbishop Fulton Sheen prophecy. The Vatican II is not a copycat of the Old Catholic Church and definitely not an example of a counterfeit. So, who or which is the perfect ecxample of a counterfeit and devoid of divine content? A group of people united to a schismatic priest celebrating illicit & invalid TLM is a perfect example of a counterfeit resembling the old catholic church. Be wise.

Comment: @jongricafort number 1, nothing in Traditionis Custodes requires that the local Bishop restrict the TLM on certain days of the year, so the argument that Cupich is obeying the Pope here falls flat. It seems much more like opportunism. Number 2, how can you say that the TLM adherents are the counterfeit church when Pope Benedict permitted its celebration and there are multiple religious orders in full and ordinary communion with Rome who have this mass as a part of their charism, as well as older version of the Mass celebrated by ordinary religious like Dominicans and Benedictines?

Comment: @jaredad7What is the fruit of Summorum P. according to the College of Bishops? TLM is sacred and beautiful that's why Satan intent to defile it at all cost. Schismatic attitude belongs to Satan. How TLM is being defile? By infecting the priest and the people to celebrate it not in full communion with Rome. Why? A sacrifice tainted w/ disobedience is not pleasing to God and will be rejected.

Comment: @jaredad7 Here is the wording on TC.-- § 3. to establish at the designated locations the days on which eucharistic celebrations are permitted using the Roman Missal promulgated by Saint John XXIII in 1962. [7] In these celebrations the readings are proclaimed in the vernacular language, using translations of the Sacred Scripture approved for liturgical use by the respective Episcopal Conferences;https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html

Comment: @jongricafort Cupich's actions here only give occasion to sin via disobedience. Vibrant parishes in Chicago which could once offer the TLM weekly for their congregation now are bound to skip the TLM at the most important and highest feasts, and also once per month minimum, or else be guilty of disobedience. Cupich has the canonical right to do what he is doing, but that doesn't mean he is acting in accordance with justice or with charity.

Comment: @jaredad7 Read CCC2477, and tell me if you understand this teaching.

Comment: There is sufficient evidence for my charge. Cupich has, in the past, attack TLM parishes without just cause, merely relying on "I'm a bishop so I have the canonical right to do this and you have to be obedient." I have spoken nothing false, and I'm not guilty of detraction because his faults in this regard are public. One example: https://rapidcityjournal.com/bishop-bans-latin-services/article_b37a5c37-b5a4-5af6-8014-48d9f5ef9da7.html

Comment: @jaredad7 Are there any Church authorities like the US Nuncio, the Congregation of Bishops and the CDF affirm your accusation on Cdl. Cupich?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132754/discussion-between-jaredad7-and-jong-ricafort).

Answer (score -2):

For one obvious reason.  The Latin Church can only properly have one rite (the way they celebrate Mass).  Since the Mass of Pope St. Paul VI, there have been two rites. Eventually there will only be one, hence the prohibition is working towards that end, as is the Pope's motu proprio.

Comment: So there's nothing special about First Sundays? Just the good cardinal trying to throw a monkey wrench in the Mass schedule?

Comment: Do you mean according to official Church teaching?

Comment: Not necessarily. just traditions are OK - like First Fridays

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these traditions (lower case 't'), but they are not binding in any way on anyone can can be suppressed or eliminated by the Pope and Bishops if they deem it worthy.  So what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.  That's what the question is, why would Cardinal Cupich pick one Sunday a month to annoy TLM goers?  Is he trying to promote _unity_ in some horrible misguided way?

Comment: Not true that the Roman Rite had just one Rite. The Church in the West had the Lyon Rite,  Aberdeen Rite as well as several other historical Roman Rites all at the same time. Do not forget the Rite of Milan of which Pope St. Paul VI came from.

Comment: At a wild guess I would say he is trying to throw the wrench in the holdouts who believe the TLM is the *only* valid mass. The will be forced to miss a mass, hear a mass they believe is invalid, or violate church discipline.

Comment: The wisdom behind Cdl.Cupich guidelines, is to know how many Trads are obedience and in full communion with the Church. Why? Traditionis Custodes is not about liturgy, its about unity in the Church. If the Trads wanted to obey and uphold unity, they will follow, but if they want disunity, they will insist in doing things their own way. Cdl.Cupich wisdom is great, as it will expose the real numbers of schismatic under his watch.

Comment: @jong sorry for the _reductio ad hitlerium_ but to quote my old piano teacher 'please engage your brain before putting your hands on the keyboard'.  Exposing schismatic faithful is insanity of Hitlerian proportions.  When all the priests who take their jobs seriously are forced out as pastors and left to wander like Fr. Z, the churches will rot, and they'll rot from the inside out.   Anybody who hates Tradition, Latin or Mass cuts themselves off from the Church, but someone who likes the Traditional Latin Mass is a scismatic,  hmm, that's curious.

Comment: @jongricafort Perhaps you would like to post an answer, rather than answering in the comments.

Comment: @PeterTurner Exposing schismatic is insanity to you, but it is the weapon Pope Francis was inspired to use in order to expose all the wolves that are attacking Pope Benedict XVI during his papacy. How to expose the wolves or schismatic bishops and cardinals occupying powerful position inside Vatican? The keyword is "Mercy", because Satan hates the "Mercy of God" and so the wolves will reject & oppose teaching magnifying the infinite mercy of God, like Amoris L. & CCC2267. Anti-christ = Anti-mercy. Did Pope Francis exposed & removed the wolves or schismatic bishops & cardinals? YES!

Comment: This is false. The Latin Church has a plethora of rites, and has since ancient times. Since the 1500s, there has been a single standardized rite for diocesan celebration, but countless Latin orders in good standing and a long history in the Church have their own rites. Two examples are the Dominicans and the Benedictines.

Comment: jaredad7, than you would have to answer why Pope Paul V suppressed all other rites regarding the one Latin rite.  These other rites are local rites and do not represent the entire Latin Church, hence your point does not apply.